# maven-compiler-plugin 3.8.4 3.9.0

Tags: maven

So far I am fine with maven-compiler-plugin 3.8.1.
However, from time to time I am updating my pom.xml in maven archetypes for keeping pace with newer versions.
With maven-compiler-plugin I am confused and like to understand.
In [maven central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin) I can find that 3.9.0 is available. However, using it in my pom.xml I get the failure

`maven-compiler-plugin:3.9.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.9.0 was not found in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt.`

Check this on the given [url](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/3.9.0/) it looks like it should have been found.

On the [maven apache site](https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html) I can see, that 3.9.0 is not released, but 3.8.4. 
How is it possible that Maven Central shows a version in release notation that is not released by its developers?

Looking for 3.8.4 on [maven central](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) reveals that the next older version before 3.9.0 is 3.8.1 - nothing in between.
Why do the developers release a maven plugin but do not load it up to Maven Central?

What am I thinking wrong here?

Comment: The Apache Maven link you have provided lists `Apache Maven` versions, not `Apache Maven Compiler Plugin` versions. They are different artifacts with different semver. You can check [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/usage.html) Apache Maven Compiler Plugin usage, where version 3.9.0 is shown.

Comment: As already mentioned you are mistaken Apache Maven (core) the tool you are calling via `mvn...` and the maven-compiler-plugin (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/). Furthermore the version 3.9.0 of the maven-compiler-plugin is available and works.. I would check the output during the build because it looks like either network/firewall issue.. Also check the rest of the output... Related to different versions there had been a number of changes which make sense to change from 3.8.2 to 3.9.0 instead (https://lists.apache.org/thread/phd2172wv99popogrp7mzmx2q0867g52).

Comment: ok - thank you and sorry for mixing maven with maven-compiler-plugin.  So it boils down to the question, why maven-compiler-plugin 3.9.0 is not downloaded. I think I did not change anything - there is no firewall - but it works now. Maybe, I should delete this question after a while.

Comment: No problem. Often this is caused by network issues.. you should think about configuring checkSum policy (https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2018/10/13/maven-artifact-checksums-what/) ... if you are in a corporate environment the best would be to use a repository manager...